# Virtual Buttons get Pressed on their own

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I have made an  AR app in Unity using Vuforia. I have some Virtual Buttons in the scene. The problem I am facing is that the virtual button is getting pressed on their own. I am not able to figure out what I am doing wrong. All the buttons are in a layer named "Buttons". Here is the virtual Button handler script:

```
    private List<GameObject> vbtns= new List<GameObject>();
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    var goArray = FindObjectsOfType<GameObject>();
    for(var i=0; i<goArray.Length; i++)
    {
        if(goArray[i].GetComponent<VirtualButtonBehaviour>())
        {
            //Debug.Log("The game component is " + goArray[i]);
            goArray[i].GetComponent<VirtualButtonBehaviour>().RegisterEventHandler(this);
            vbtns.Add(goArray[i]);
        }

    }

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}

public void OnButtonPressed(VirtualButtonAbstractBehaviour vb)
{
    Debug.Log("Button Pressed.");
    Debug.Log("The name of the vbutton is "+ vb.VirtualButtonName);
    SceneManager.LoadScene("scene_"+vb.VirtualButtonName,LoadSceneMode.Single);

}

public void OnButtonReleased(VirtualButtonAbstractBehaviour vb)
{
    Debug.Log("Button Released");
}
```

Please suggest what could be the reason for this. I have attached the screenshot of the game view below. Thanks in advance.
   [image: This is how the scene appears in the game view.]

Comment: Does this happen when you only use one button?

Comment: Can you post some screen shots of button?

Comment: It works fine when there is only one button.

Comment: I had the same issue. My guess is that the camera cannot recognise the marker very well. Meaning that Vuforia tries to detect features on the marker but cannot.